# Get Firebase Collection into simple array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to react all items from a collection in Firebase into an array so I can use later in React.

I have this currently:

```
  const retrievegear = firebase.firestore().collection('gear').get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const check = doc.data().Name;
        console.log(check);
    });
  });
```

Which is fine - it shows me all the Names of the items in the gear collection. But I want it within an array and only want some of the fields in the collection.

I am then using this array to populate checkboxes - so I need const declared somewhere so that my return can access it.

Answer (score 2):

The Firestore `get()` method is asynchronous and returns a Promise, so it’s only in the callback function passed to [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) that you get its result.

Consequently you need to do as follows:

```
const myArray = [];
firebase.firestore().collection('gear').get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const check = doc.data().Name;
        console.log(check);
        myArray.push(check);
    });
    // Here do whatever you want with the myArray array which contains the data from the collection

  });
```

---

If you want to transform this code in a function that you can call from other places in your code, do as follows (we use async/await for readability):

```
async function getGearData() {
    const myArray = [];
    const querySnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('gear').get();
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const check = doc.data().Name;
        console.log(check);
        myArray.push(check);
    });
    return myArray;
}
```

Note that **this function is asynchronous**, so you need to call it as follows:

```
getGearData()
.then(gearData => {
  // Here and only here you get the value 
  console.log(gearData);
  // ....
})
```

---

Note that you can also use the `map()` method on the array returned by `querySnapshot.docs`.

Comment: OK, thank you - but how would I then load this myArray into a constant that I can use  later?

Comment: See the update. In any case you need to deal with the asynchronous aspect.