# Capturing data out of a firebase collection, and actually making it usable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in firebase called "polls". The collection is an array, and within the array I have 4 urls (url_a, url_b, url_c, and url_d). I want to pull these urls out of the array in my react app so I can use them as the src for 4 different images.

I know since "polls" is an array, I can't just pull the urls directly by setting some variable to "polls.data.url_a". With the 2nd useEffect function in the code below, I'm able to console.log the array
and the data within it using forEach. I can console.log poll.data, and even poll.data.url_a and it returns the proper result.

But I am stuck on how to get outside of that forEach and actually capture the individual urls to where I can assign them to a variable so I can make use of them.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore"
import { db } from '../firebase.config'


function Food() {
  const [polls, setPolls] = useState([])


  useEffect(() => {
    getPolls()
  }, [])


 ** useEffect(() => {
    polls.forEach((poll) => 
    console.log(poll.data.url_a))
}, [polls])
**
function getPolls() {

    const pollsRef = collection(db, 'polls');
    
   getDocs(pollsRef).then(response => {
      const poll = response.docs.map(doc => ({data: doc.data(), id: doc.id}))
      setPolls(poll)
    }).catch(error => console.log(error.message))
  
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      Food
    </div>
  )
}

export default Food
```

I've tried setting a variable within the forEach and calling it later, and running a forEach later on in the function. But I just don't know how to get to the URL in a usable way, outside of just console logging it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you use `polls` in your rendering code, it should automatically be reexecuted when you call `setPolls`. Is that not happening? Can you edit your question to show how you tried to use the data in the rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Check out what Renaud suggested here to see how to assign variables: [Get Firebase Collection into simple array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69702629/get-firebase-collection-into-simple-array?rq=1)

If I understand what you're asking, you'll need the poll const to instead point towards a global store variable or to reference it within the template section.

Answer (score 0):

If the data your fetching is structured like this:

```js
const polls = [{
  data: {
    url_a: "url a",
    url_b: "url b"
  }
}]
```

It's easier to just assign it to an `object` state variable instead of an `array`.

```js
const [polls, setPolls] = useState({})
// ...
useEffect(() => {
  getPolls()
}, [polls])

function getPolls() {

  const pollsRef = collection(db, 'polls');

  getDocs(pollsRef).then(response => {
    const polls = response.docs.map(doc => ({data: doc.data(), id: doc.id}))
    polls.map(poll => setPolls(poll.data))
  }).catch(error => console.log(error.message))
}
// ...
  return <img src={polls.url_a} alt="" />
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! I knew it was going to be something super simple like this that I was overlooking ha.